# Unable to use SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(MATCH))) combination as a range in a LOOKUP function in Excel

Tags: excel, lookup, reverse-lookup

I have an Excel sheet containing a matrix of [Year & Week number] in rows and [name of Employees] in row1 giving values of available weekly hours.

[image: Excel_Query_Data]

I am able to successfully use the Excel formula

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((A:A=2018)*(B:B=31)),D:D)
```

at cell F2 for a reverse lookup. It gives the result **15** correctly.

However, I wanted to replace range D:D in the above formula to a dynamic range  by identifying the column when the employee is known.

So I tried replacing by the formula

```
SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Employee2",1:1,0),4),"1","") &":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Employee2",1:1,0),4),"1","")
```

This portion of the formula works and gives **D:D** for Employee2. This is shown to work in cell F4.

But the revised formula gives an error of **#Value!** at cell F6.

It says "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type."
The revised formula which does not work is:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((A:A=2018)*(B:B=31)),SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Employee2",1:1,0),4),"1","") &":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Employee2",1:1,0),4),"1",""))
```

I hope someone can help show me where I am making an error in trying to replace range D:D in the LOOKUP formula with the combination of SUBSTITUTE, ADDRESS & MATCH functions.

Thanks to all trying to help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just plug a string, which is what SUBSTITUTE returns into a formula.

You can use INDERICT to turn the string into a viable reference:

```
INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Employee2",1:1,0),4),"1","") &":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Employee2",1:1,0),4),"1",""))
```

But both INDIRECT and ADDRESS are volatile.

Use instead INDEX to return the correct column:

```
INDEX(A:AAA,0,MATCH("Employee2",1:1,0))
```

So your formula is:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((A:A=2018)*(B:B=31)),INDEX(A:AAA,0,MATCH("Employee2",1:1,0)))
```

Comment: Hi Scott, Your solution works perfectly! Thanks for your swift response. Can you also please help me understand how the INDEX function works with the row_num argument as zero. Thanks again.

Comment: `0` returns all the rows in the column.

Comment: please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.